# Which database table store group child product qty?

Tags: magento2, grouped-products

[image]

I am try to change grouped product first qty in this two table **cataloginventory_stock_item** & **inventory_source_item** but changes not reflect.
so please guide me which is right table for storing group child product q

Comment: The table name is "cataloginventory_stock_status"

Answer (score 1):

The right table is `catalog_product_link_attribute_decimal`.